# Regex that validates both IPv4 address and domain name

Tags: javascript, regex, ipv4

```
if (isValidDomainName(addr)) {
     return true;
}
else if (isValidIPv4(addr)) {
     return true;
}

function isValidIPv4(addr){
    var regex = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])$/;
    return regex.test(addr);
}

function isValidDomainName(name){
   var regex =/^((www\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63})|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}))(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,63})?$/;
   return regex.test(name);
}
```

This is the code I have written. I am facing some issues. Let me give some examples:

- `google.com` - valid domain name(expected)
- `192.15.67.34` - valid ipv4 address(expected)
- `192.45.dd.33`

  EXPECTED : invalid ip

  ACTUAL :Valid domain name because the current system validates it as it passes the domain name constraint
- `192.67.77.xx`

  EXPECTED : invalid ip

  ACTUAL :Valid domain name because the current system validates it as it passes the domain name constraint

Please pour in some valuable comments.

Comment: About this `192.67.77.xx` I don't see many ways around it, because it's not like the regex is failing. That *is* a valid domain name.

Comment: Given the current form of your question, my answer won't help you very much. It seems you're trying to achieve something too complex with regex. You should probably write an algorithm that fits your specific needs. Your regex for domain name is already barely readable and seems to impose very specific constraints

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, a domain name can be any sequence of "blocks" comprised of a combination of ASCII letters, digits and symbol  `-`, blocks being separated by `.`. It can be maximum 255 characters long and must end with a primary domain name.

Given that primary domains could be anything defined as block up there, by this definition, `192.45.dd.33` and `192.67.77.xx` **are** valid domain names.

Why don't you validate your input as an IP address, and then validate it as domain only if it's not recognized as a valid IP ?

```js
function isValid(addr) {
  if (isValidIPv4(addr)) {
    return true;
  } else if (isValidDomainName(addr)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isValidIPv4(addr){
    var regex = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])$/;
    return regex.test(addr);
}

function isValidDomainName(name){
   var regex =/^((www\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63})|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}))(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,63})?$/;
   return regex.test(name);
}

for (addr of [
  '192.168.1.52','192.168.1.xx', '192.ww.1.0', '255.255.255.000',
  'my-domain.com', 'my$IPp.com', 'google.192'
  ]) {
  console.log(addr, isValidIPv4(addr), isValidDomainName(addr), isValid(addr));
}
```

Comment: "Why don't you validate your input as an IP address, and then validate it as domain only if it's not recognized as a valid IP?" wouldn't that have the same effect, i.e. that `192.67.77.xx` will be validated as a domain name?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it would indeed. But shouldn't it ? Now the question has been edited and it appears clearer that OP would like to detect *failed attempts* to input an IP address. How this should be done depends vastly on context, which we don't have.